# apollo's useQuery data does not update after client.resetStore()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am having an issue with `useQuery` from `@apollo/client`

I have a `Navbar` component

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);

  console.log('navbar', data)

  return <ReactStuff />
}
```

And I also have a `UserProfile` component which allows the user to logout via a button. When the user presses the button, this code is ran:

```js
const {
  getCurrentUser,
  changePassword,
  changePasswordData,
  logoutUser,
} = useUsers();

const logout = () => {
  logoutUser();
  localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
  props.history.push("/");
};
```

`useUsers` is a custom hook which houses the resetStore function:

```js
const useUser = () => {
  const { client, loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);
    
  const logoutUser = () => {
    console.log("firing logout user");
    client
      .resetStore()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("here in reset store success");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("here in error");
      }); // causes uncaught error when logging out.
    };
    
  return {
    // other useUser functions
    logoutUser
  }
}
```

Now I can't for the life of me figure out why the `Navbar` component, does not get updated when `logout` is pressed.

I have a `withAuth` higher-order component which does the exact same query, and this works absolutely fine. The user is sent to the /login page, and If I was to `console.log(data)` it is updated as undefined - as expected.

```js
import { GET_CURRENT_USER } from "../graphql/queries/user";

/**
 * Using this HOC
 * we can check to see if the user is authed
 */
const withAuth = (Component) => (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);

  if (error) console.warn(error);
  if (loading) return null;

  if (data && data.user) {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }

  if (!data) {
    history.push("/login");
    return "null";
  }

  return null;
};
```

For some reason, this `useQuery` inside `Navbar` is holding onto this stale data for some reason and I can't figure out how to make it work correctly.

Update 1:

I've changed the `logoutUser` function to use `clearStore()` and the same thing happens, the Navbar is not updated, but I am redirected to `/login` and withAuth is working as intended.

```
const logoutUser = () => {
  client
    .clearStore()
    .then((data) => console.log(data)) // logs []
    .catch((err) => console.log(err)); // no error because no refetch
  };
```

Comment: Did you check if the navbar is re-rendering after you logout by console logging the user data inside the Navbar component?

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the store to reset, probably the redirection and storage clean up happen before the reset completes, try doing that once it has finished

```js
const logout = () => {
  logoutUser(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
    props.history.push('/');
  });
};

const logoutUser = onLogout => {
  console.log('firing logout user');
  client
    .resetStore()
    .then(data => {
      onLogout();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('here in error');
    }); // causes uncaught error when logging out.
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue. I removed the `props.history.push('/`)` and still faced the issue. It is because I am removing the localStorage authToken and then the client.resetStore() is doing all queries and erroing becausing it's not authenticated.

Comment: @KarlTaylor Then what you're missing is the error handling in the navbar component, check when it receives an auth error, and show the unauthenticated navbar version

Comment: That is not what I am missing. I do not need to handle the error in the NavBar component, the error simply should not occur for this use case - the user simply logs out, and the new navbar needs to be displayed. I found my answer here https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5941#issuecomment-749815937

Answer (score 0):

Check: do you have only ONE ApolloClient instance?

In some cases, if you configuring ApolloClient in the custom class or file you can implicitly create multiple apolloClient instances, for example by 'import' statement. In that case you clearing only one of the caches you made.